# what line(s) of code do I need to add to my function?

Tags: python, file

after the if (i>0) i added code:

```
obj1 = "Since i is greater than 0, lst[i-1] will become equal to the 'temp'/n"
wds = obj1.split()
file1.write(str(wds))
```

However, I am fairly certain this is correct.  What do I need to do to write my explanation (obj1) of a portion of the sorting process to filename?

```
def sortAndExplain(lst, filename):
    """This function takes two inputs: LST, a list of values and 
    FILENAME, a string that is the name of the file that will be 
    edited. The function opens FILENAME, sorts LST, and writing 
    explanations and/or the current ordering of LST as the sorting 
    of LST proceeds."""
    file1 = open(filename, 'w')
    done = False        
    while not done:     
        i = len(lst) - 1           
        while ((i > 0) and (lst[i] >= lst[i-1])): 
            i = i - 1 
            """Add a line here writes the current ordering of LST 
            into FILENAME on one line. Each ordering should be on 
            its own line.""" 
            file1.write(str(lst))
        if (i > 0):  
            temp = lst[i]   
            lst[i] = lst[i-1]
            lst[i-1] = temp
            """Add a line here that writes an explanation of what 
            happened in this conditional statement into FILENAME on 
            one line. Each explanation should be on its own line.""" 
            obj1 = "Since i is > than 0, lst[i-1] will become equal to 'temp'/n"
            wds = obj1.split()
            file1.write(str(wds))
        else:              
            done = True  
    file1.close()
```

Comment: There's no need to split your explanation and then re-stringify it. Just `write` the string directly.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

That describes only the one line.  I expect that you need to describe the entire block.  The three lines swap the values of **lst[i]** and **lst[i-1]**; **temp** is incidental to the process.

In case you haven't yet recognized the high-level process, this is a standard algorithm known as a "bubble sort".  You can search the explanation from there.  Wikipedia will have a good one.